# Reading and Distinguishing Dates in a cell, then return mean date

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I don't have advanced experience in vba, so please take it easy on me :)

Each cell in a particular column of my sheet, can contain dates in the form `19/12/15, 22/12/15`; This can be for example `C10`'s value (just to mention, it's really up to me to request from the users to input dates in any of these cells in one or another form, but I find the above explicit way, in terms of both processing and clarity, the most convenient).

Following I put a sample of how cells look like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twR9u.png)

The task here is simply to read the cell's value, distinguish the dates which can be two or more, and return a mean date. In the case of an odd difference it should return the date closer to the lower bound.

I have tried various pre-built vba date functions just to separate and split the dates but none have worked. Also, I used `split` function return `0`, whenever I pass a cell's value as an argument. 
Do you have any suggestions on how to do that?

Thanks!

**Edit**: I have been able to come up with the following function which does the job for the case that the dates are inserted to a cell in a standard format, e.g. `##/##/##, ##/##/##`, and also if there are no more than two dates inserted in the cell. If anyone finds a better method please feel free to contribute it.

```
Function MeanDate(cell As Range) As Date
 Dim InvoiceDate As String
 Dim FirstInvoiceDate As String
 Dim SecondInvoiceDate As String
 Dim meanInvDate As String
 Dim DaysOfDiff As Long
 InvoiceDate = cell.Value
 If Len(InvoiceDate) = 8 Then
   MeanDate = ActiveCell.Value
 Else
   FirstInvoiceDate = DateValue(Mid(InvoiceDate, 1, 8))
   SecondInvoiceDate = DateValue(Mid(InvoiceDate, 11, 8))
   DaysOfDiff = DateDiff("d", FirstInvoiceDate, SecondInvoiceDate)
   MeanDate = DateAdd("d", Round((DaysOfDiff / 2), 0), DateValue(FirstInvoiceDate))
 End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TextTo columns

```
Sub Macro1()  
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("E:E"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :="-", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 4), Array(1, 4)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True   
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I am afraid that this does not work for the task I need!